# SSH with multi-factor authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, authentication, 2-factor-authentication

The customer requires us to setup MFA for SSH sessions. I have successfully tested MFA using Google Authenticator by following this article: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-one-time-passwords-for-two-factor-authentication-with-ssh-on-centos/.

However, the problem is that other staff member need access to the system also. They can contact me each time for a verification code but I would rather not do this. I can create multiple accounts and setup up MFA for each person. This would mean they have to be physically with me or I can get them to scan the QR code through Teams. It just means there's a lot of administrative effort on my end.

I have thought of SMS to groups but not sure if this is possible though. I think this is a little less secure but saves a lot of effort on my end. Is this a possible alternative?

Any other suggestion on what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you consider solution with hardware-dongles like FIDO2? Does the client demand the authentication scheme to involve third party services for one-time-passwords?

Comment: I am not sure how FIDO2 keys solve my problem as we access the server remotely. The client simply requires MFA for SSH sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL approach, see [github google-authenticator-libpam repo](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam).

> If your system does not have this (QR code) library, **you can either
> follow the URL that google-authenticator outputs**, or you have to
> manually enter the alphanumeric secret key into the Android "Google
> Authenticator" application.